# Advice with Loops in my JAVA code

Tags: java, loops, nested-loops

I have this program that I am currently working on and need help adding a loop to it. Its a word guessing puzzle game and each player should be able to guess as many letters as possible until they guess a wrong letter. It will then move on to the next player.
Right now it only asks each player 1 time for a letter then it goes on to the next player and so on, then the program ends.
Any advice would be very appreciated.
Here's my code so far:

```
public class PuzzleGuess{

 public static void main(String []args){

    System.out.println("Welcome!!");

    System.out.println("Availble letters:");

    String[] letter = new String[]{"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"};

    for(int a=0;a<26;a++)

      System.out.print(letter[a]);

      System.out.println("");

    System.out.println("_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _");

    String[] Guess = new String[]{"S", "W", "E", "E", "T", "H", "O", "M", "E", "A", "L", "A", "B", "A", "M", "A"};

    System.out.println("No of players:"+3);

   int ch,flag=0,r;

    String s;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    for(int i=1;i<=3;i++)

    {

        System.out.println("players:"+i);

        System.out.println("Select any one 1) spin wheel 2) Guess");

        ch=scan.nextInt();

        if(ch==1)

        {

            Random t = new Random();

            r=t.nextInt(10)+1;

            if(r==1)

            {

              System.out.println("you are landed on $100.");

            }

              else if(r==2)

              {

              System.out.println("you are landed on $300.");

              }

              else if(r==3)

              {

              System.out.println("you are landed on $500.");

            }

              else if(r==4)

              {

              System.out.println("you are landed on $700.");

              }

              else if(r==5)

              {

              System.out.println("you are landed on $900.");

              }

              else if(r==6)

              {

              System.out.println("you are landed on $2000.");

              }

              else if(r==7)

              {

              System.out.println("you are landed on $3000.");

              }

             else if(r==8)

              {

              System.out.println("you are landed on $5000.");

              }

              else if(r==9)

              {

              System.out.println("you are landed on $-1000.");

              }

              else

              {

              System.out.println("you are landed on $0.");

              }

        }

        else if(ch==2)

      {

            System.out.println("Select your letter from available letters ");

            s = scan.next();

            for(int g=0;g<16;g++)

            {



                 if(s.equals(Guess[g]))

                 {

                     flag=1;



                 }

            }

            if(flag==1)

            {

                System.out.println("correct");

                for(int a=0;a<26;a++)

              {

                    if(s.equals(letter[a]))

                    {

                        letter[a]=null;

                    }

                }

                for(int a=0;a<26;a++)

                 System.out.print(letter[a]);

                 System.out.println("");



            }

            else

            {

                System.out.println("Incorrect");
```

Comment: Please don't post your code with a hundred blank lines in it. It is needlessly difficult to read.

Comment: _Any advice would be appreciated_ is the kind of question that is off-topic for StackOverflow. You should consider looking at the CodeReview Stack Exchange to see if your question fits the requirements for what is on-topic for their site as this question _may_ be a fit there.

Answer (score 0):

Start by create some objects and methods in which you will move your code.
You should split your code to simplify comprehension of your code.